# How do I navigate to a subdirectory named with a single character using only a wildcard in cmd/batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Suppose I need to navigate to a sub-folder using the wildcard character `*`. What is the command in cmd/batch script?

Example:

My current directory is `c:\Users\Test`

I have only one sub-folder as `3`

I want to navigate to `c:\Users\Test\3`

> cd * //doesn't work
>
> cd *. * //doesn't work

What is the command to navigate?

Comment: Its in batch script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could choose one random/the first directory found by a FOR-Loop

```
for /d %%A in (*) do cd %%A
```

Comment: When I execute,I am getting like
 %%A was unexpected at this time.

Comment: When you try to start it from the cmd-prompt, you need this `for /d %A in (*) do cd %A`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure?  This is working in my environment:

```
PS C:\users\myuser\test> ls


    Directory: C:\users\myuser\test


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         9/18/2013   9:56 AM            3


PS C:\users\myuser\test> cd *
PS C:\users\myuser\test\3>
```

This *would not work* if you try to use it in a directory that has multiple sub-directories.  For example, my "Documents" folder has multiple subdirectories:

```
PS C:\users\myUser\documents> cd *
Set-Location : Cannot set the location because path '*' resolved to multiple
containers. You can only the set location to a single container at a time.
```

Here's what happens when I try to use the wildcard to match for certain incomplete phrases that are specific enough to return a single match:

```
PS C:\users\myUser\documents> cd boo*
PS C:\users\myUser\documents\Books>
PS C:\users\myUser\documents> cd *ooks
PS C:\users\myUser\documents\Books>
```

Comment: @Earnest That would have been helpful to include in the question body.